# Restoring TikTok Scrolbar

Tags: html, css, scrollbar

I am building browser extension for use on tiktok and in my injected code i require a scrollbar however tiktoks css is preventing this and i cant find out how to overide it.

I have tried a lot of things to overcome it but maybe there is a property im just not thinking of.

Its not as simple as setting overflow to auto globally, and i have tried to reset:

```
::-webkit-scrollbar
```

but i am at a loss as to how to get a scroll bar to appear.

Can anyone maybe take a look at the tiktok site and see if you can tell whats blocking any scrollbar

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I found out what was removing the scrollbars.

They had:

```
html[pc="yes"] *::-webkit-scrollbar {
width: 0px;
height: 0px;
```

}

I was able to unset these values then create a scrollbar on the element i needed it

```
#t3_scroll_container::-webkit-scrollbar {
width: unset!important;
height: unset!important;
}

#t3_scroll_container::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 10px;
}


#t3_scroll_container::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  background: #f1f1f1; 
}


#t3_scroll_container::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background: #888; 
}


#t3_scroll_container::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
  background: #555; 
}
```